# Regex to match multilines with lines feeds and text

Tags: python, regex

Consider you have the following text below to parse:
And I want to get the value after Fetch key only( until the last comma not included) (`239847238974982374897289347982374892734897238947892374892374892374`)

`<some_xml="SDFSDF_sd\S-1-sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf">
Key1:
3A68686BGGHJ12,
Fetch:
239847238974982374897289347982374892734897238947892374892374892374,
{sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf}:
</some_xml>`

My regex for doing this is: `<some_xml.*>[\s.]*Fetch:([^,]*)`
For some reason the `[\s.]` isn't capturing all possible redundant info before my `Fetch` key, can you explain why?

Whole example is [here](https://regex101.com/r/qV7zR3/2)

**Edit**: my regex was missing * after the first [] group, but still the same problem, fixed version [here](https://regex101.com/r/qV7zR3/3)- but same problem exist

Comment: use an xml parser.

Comment: How could XMl parser help me here, why can't I do that with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part `[\s.]*` matches any number of spaces or a full stops, but only these. You're probably looking for something like `.*?`. It might work but there really are some other issues here as well. E.g. `<some_xml.*>` will skip a whole tag if there are more than one, since `.*` matches as much as it possibly can.

Se the regex *work* [here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wS9nH4/1) and notice how it skips the first section and selects the string in the second.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the insight for the xml tag , how would you solved it?

Comment: As mentioned in a comment above 1. use an XML-parser to extract the inner text (between the `<some_xml>` and the `</some_xml>`), 2. iterate through them if multiple, 3. **Then** use the regex (`Fetch:([^,]*)`) to extract the text.

Comment: Okay, but I guess we can do all thing in regex, see my updated suggestion upon yours, I've added ?

Comment: If you absolutely must do it using regex, the easy fix is to add a `?` to make the first `.*` non greedy - i.e. `<some_xml.*?>.*?Fetch:([^,]*)`.

Comment: However I was wondering if you have an idea why in my suggested answer the ungreedy expression `.*?`, doesn't work as in yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<some_xml.*>(?:\s|.)*Fetch:([^,]*)
            ^^^^^^^^
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/qV7zR3/4)

It was failing because `[\s.]` was matching `.` character literally.

Comment: `(?:\s|.)*` is one of the worst subpatterns I have seen - please *never* use it (unless it is not elasticsearch).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found another way but with same problem in catching in a greedy way the next instance of the same xml tag.

Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/eM5yY8/1)

**Edit:** Got it, here is a [fixed](https://regex101.com/r/eM5yY8/2) one